# Should I greet my customer at 6pm with "good evening" or "good afternoon"?

Tags: word-choice

How should I greet my customer if I meet him/her at 6pm for a discussion? Should I say "good evening" or should I say "good afternoon"?

From my understanding, "good evening" is used at around 6pm, while "good afternoon" is used for from noon time until around 6pm.

Comment: How about *hello*?

Comment: I don't think I will greet my customer "Hello" as it seems a bit quite of impolite.

Comment: *Hello* isn't impolite, and you could always add *welcome*. At least in the US, I very rarely hear *good afternoon* or *good evening* used as a sincere greeting - they sound stilted and formal. More typical is a *hi, welcome* when you walk in, followed by a *have a nice day* when you walk out.

Comment: What @onomato said: “Hello” or “How do you do?” are both perfectly fine. They are not in any way impolite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both "Good afternoon" and "Good evening" are perfectly appropriate greetings at 6pm. Pick one, and don't overanalyze it. If you say "Good evening" at 4pm, or "Good afternoon" at 8pm, you might get funny looks, but near the boundary, either is fine.

Comment: +1. Thanks Peter. Just wanted to look polite and correct when I meet my customer at 6pm and so must be sure which term for greeting is more suitable.

Answer (score 9):

*Good afternoon* before sunset, *Good evening* after it?

Comment: What about the far north or south, when sunset may be at 3pm or 11pm? Or even further north or south where you will have days with no sunset/sunrise and only darkness or daylight?

Comment: @Barrie That seems unlikely to work, as sunset more probably delimits *Good evening* and *Good night*.  Moreover, in northern climes, sunset occurs too late in summer, eg after 9PM, or too early in winter, eg before 5:30pm, to work well

Comment: Alright, already. Then I think the answer is, it all depends.

Comment: And there's a similar problem around midday.

Comment: +1.  The answer depends on the time of year; let the sun guide you.

Comment: @MonicaCellio. +1 for your sentence - "let the sun guide you"

Comment: +1 to this answer. That's what I would do. If it's still light, then Good afternoon, if dark, then good evening. There really isn't a cut-off time for saying them.

Comment: It never occurred to me that there might be any other way to do this than precisely what you have stated.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is largely regional.  In many places, "evening" starts at dusk, in others it starts at "dinner time" (6-7pm?) or "after business hours" (5pm).

My personal preference is usually to say "Good afternoon" until around 5pm, and then I switch to "Good evening."  But you can always just avoid the situation and say "Hello!" instead. :)

Comment: Do you think that "Greeting" would be a better word to greet my customer or are there better word out there?

Comment: There are many such words, depending on the nature of your business and clients. "Greetings!" would sound corny where I'm from (central U.S.), but "Welcome!" "Come in!" "How are you today?" "Thank you for calling Radio Shack, you've got questions, we've got answers. My name is Larry. How can I help you?" could all have promise. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the "good x" greeting is (in theory) expressing a wish on your part that the other person is having a positive experience of x at the moment, and will continue to do so for the remainder of x.  It doesn't really include past events.

So "good morning" at 10 am suggests "I hope you are happy at the moment, and enjoy the rest of the morning" but not "I hope you had a good breakfast".

Since by your definition at 6 pm the afternoon ends, you should say "good evening", because there is no afternoon left for them to enjoy.

Comment: It’s all about the sun, nothing else.  It can’t be evening until the westering sun has sunk below the horizon.

Answer (score -1):

5pm is the cutoff time for afternoon to evening.

Answer (score -1):

Wow! Surprised by all the opinions.  Here's mine with a little bit more of logic of my own and also told by my father (last century...really! :) and the military.
Morning technically starts at 00.00 hrs. (military time), and goes to 11:59 am. But since MOST of us sleep during those hours, generally we say morning from 6:00 am to 11:59 am.  At 12:00 hrs. it's pm (past meridian) and it is until 18:00 hrs. (12+6=18). After that 18:01 hrs. it is evening.
Don't get carried away with such details of where in the planet you are or where the sun is, just be logical. As an example, while in a cruise in Scandinavian countries and close  to Stockholm, St. Petersburg, in April it was 22:00 (10 pm) and the it almost as bright as 5 pm. So being logical it would be evening and not afternoon.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, the main confusion is in Afternoon & evening. I would say from 12 PM till 6 PM "Good Evening"cause behind it is the Sun. It sets around 6-7 PM. Average time may be 6 PM (comparing Summers & winters).